# what are the basic points to improve security on a php page?

Tags: php, sql, security, database-connection

Some security points about get and post functions in php. and about sql connection in php so that i can save my website from crakers.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some of the basic security tips covered by Steve in this blog <strike>[5 Basic PHP Security Tips](http://web.archive.org/web/20120119152916/http://www.ultramegatech.com/blog/2009/08/5-basic-php-security-tips/)</strike> which I hope you will find useful in your quest

---

**UPDATE**
The above link has been made redundant for a while now but here are some of the details covered in the article:

**1. Input Filtering**

Assume everything is dirty until proven clean. Filtering all data from external sources is probably the most important security measure you can take. This can be as easy as running some simple built-in functions on your variables.

When it comes to accepting user input, never directly use anything in `$_GET` or `$_POST`. Check each value to make sure it is something expected and assign it to a local variable for use.

```
// input filtering examples

// Make sure it is an integer
$integer = intval($_POST['variable_name']);

// Make it safe to use in a URL
$url_string = urlencode($_POST['variable_name']);
You can also check a value against a list of acceptable values. Here are two methods of doing this:

$page = 'home'; // initialize the variable

// Check input against a white-list of known options
$valid_options = array();
$valid_options[] = 'home';
$valid_options[] = 'downloads';
$valid_options[] = 'about';

if(in_array($_GET['page'], $valid_options))
{
   $page = $_GET['page'];
}

// OR this also works
switch($_GET['page'])
{
   case 'home':
   case 'downloads':
   case 'about':
      $page = $_GET['page'];
      break;
}
```

PHP as of version 5.2 provides a set of filtering functions designed just for the purpose of filtering user data. The `filter_input()` function is used to access a filtered version of input variables. This way you never have to touch the raw input via the `$_GET` or `$_POST` arrays.

```
// filter_input examples

// Make sure it is an integer
$integer = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'variable_name', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

// Make it safe to use in a URL
$url_string = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'variable_name', FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);

// Make sure it is a valid URL
$url = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'variable_name', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

**2. Output Filtering**

It is also important to filter what comes out of your applications. You want to avoid outputting the wrong characters and breaking the page rendering. This is also important in order to block certain attacks involving JavaScript injected by malicious users. There are a few functions to know for cleaning up text to display to the user:

```
$text = '<a href="test">Test</a>';
echo htmlspecialchars($text); // &lt;a href=&quot;test&quot;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
echo strip_tags($text); // Test
```

**3. Database Queries**

If your application uses a database to store data, this is another source of potential vulnerabilities. SQL Injection is a very common attack that involves maliciously crafted user input designed to change the logic of a query. This potentially allows the user to run any kind of query or bypass security measures. Stopping it is usually as easy as properly escaping data, or using prepared statements.

```
// $db refers to database connection resource/object
$name = "O'reilly"; // Contains a quote that will break the query

// MySQL via mysql_*
$safe = mysql_real_escape_string($name, $db);

// MySQL via MySQLi
$safe = $db->escape_string($name); // OOP Style
$safe = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $name); // Procedural Style

// PostgreSQL
$safe = pg_escape_string($db, $name);

// Generic (last resourt)
$safe = addslashes($name);
```

**4. Hide Your Errors**

It's never a good idea to show the world your errors. Not only does it make you look bad, it also might give malicious users another clue to help them break your site. You should always have `display_errors` disabled in a production environment, but continue logging errors with `log_errors` for your own information.

These PHP configuration directives are suitable for a production server:

```
display_errors 0
log_errors 1
```

**5. Use POST for Dangerous Actions**

There are two common methods used to send data to a PHP application, `GET` and `POST`. `GET` works by adding variables to the end of URL's (eg. `http://www.example.com/process.php?action=delete&id=123`). `POST` works by sending variables in the body of the request (normal users will not see them). It is important to carefully consider which method to use for a certain task.

You should generally stick to POST when you are performing a potentially dangerous action (like deleting something). The reason is that is is much easier to trick a user into accessing a URL with GET parameters than it is to trick them into sending a POST request. Take this example:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/process.php?action=delete&id=123" />
```

If a user with an active session on your site visits another web page with the above image tag, the user's browser will quietly send a request to your site telling it to delete record 123.

Keep in mind that other precautions should also be taken to ensure requests are legitimate under a secure session. It is also easily possible to create a form that does the same as above using a POST request, so don't assume that method is "safe" either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to secure your application against SQL injection you must use these functions in your code :

- **intval()** : To get int values from Get or Post
- **floatval()** : To get floats
- **doubleval()** : to get doubles

For the string values you can use one of these functions :

- **addslashes()** : If you haven't any DB Connection yet
- **mysql_real_escape_string()** : the php tests the String input for you before sending it to the database if you are using MySQL

I wish these tips could help you because they helped me a lot

Regards
NiL

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how much effort you want to put into it. If you want the first principles, the other answers already provide some clues. If you want to provide security guarantees however...

Covering the web security topic fully takes a book's worth of information, so this cannot be done by a blog post or a stackoverflow reply.

A good start is looking at the detailed verification requirements of [OWASP ASVS Level 1](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Application_Security_Verification_Standard_Project). ASVS is a standard for verifying the security of a web app before you ship it. Level 1 is the minimum level of security process you need to have to be able to make statements about the security of the app. Anything less and you simply cannot know whether the app is wide-open or not.

Other OWASP projects that are also helpful:

- [OWASP development guide](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Guide_Project) (incomplete)
- [OWASP ESAPI](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Enterprise_Security_API) (security API's to assist in correctly implementing the best practices)

Answer (score -1):

This is the most comprehensive PHP application security checklist I've seen

http://www.sk89q.com/2010/04/printable-php-security-checklist/

Comment: Link does not exist.  Also, if you provide links put it as comment not as answer

Answer (score -2):

Regarding SQL, make sure it only listens on localhost, 127.0.0.1. This has been the default for MySQL for several years now, but older installations used to listen to the outside world, exposing your server. I realize this only answers part of your question, but I personally don't believe PHP can be secure.

Comment: Why PHP can't be secure, if I may ask?

Comment: because no language is secure, and PHP is a language that has grown by accretion, which IMO makes it less so. it's just a belief, no data to back it up.